# Matching renders from Maya to Blender?

Tags: rendering

Does anyone have an tips for matching renders from Maya to Blender?

I am having a problem where that the same model in the same position gives a slightly distorted result when rendered in Blender. Overall it looks like the entire render in Blender is not at wide as Maya's default render. Other than stretching the objects' width, it there another way to fix this error?

[image: comparison]

Comment: The color render on top is the Maya render, the bottom one is Blender's render.

Comment: Have you check the camera settings?

Comment: @DS89 I adjusted the FOV to 31.112 as mentioned in this post: http://forums.cgsociety.org/archive/index.php?t-954198.html

So far no luck though, the images are still distorted. I'm trying a few other things. Any idea which settings might help adjust this error? Thanks!

Comment: I only see one picture.

Comment: @metaphor_set I think there are two images overlapped. I guess you have to match the camera FOV settings in both applications, I'd guess they use the same units and results would be the same, if not you will either have to eyeball it or find some sort of math formula for accurate conversion  between systems.

Comment: Yes, the images are overlapped to show the difference between the two. 

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos I'll have to try some other FOV and see if any of those work. Thanks!